# Cpanel IMAP Gmail problems?

Tags: php, gmail, imap, cpanel, gmail-imap

I'm trying to connect to my gmail account via IMAP on a 000webhost domain but I doesn't seem to be working even though they say that they support IMAP
Here's my PHP code:

```
$server="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$inbox = imap_open($server,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

for "$username" and "$password" I'm using my Gmail email and my Gmail password (e.g. myaccount@gmail.com and mypassword)

This just gives me an error saying that it can't open the stream and that it is an invalid remote specification.
Any ideas of what this might be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you contacted your hosts's support?

Comment: Is this on a real server or are you running this PHP locally?

Answer (score -3):

Gmail uses just the account name as login, not the full email address.